# Filtering list based on items with record syntax

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to filter my list of items on it's properties, I just can't seem t get it to work.

I have a datatype Figure which is declared as follows:

```
data Shape = Square {length:: Float, color:: Color}
           | Rectangle {length:: Float, widht:: Float, color :: Color}
            ....
```

repeat this for a couple of shapes
The propery they all have in common is color, which also is a data type `data Color = Yellow | Green | Blue`

I tried filtering on color like this

```
getByColor :: Color -> [Shape] -> [Shape]
getByColor _ [] = []
getByColor x item@{color=c}:xs
                             | c == x = item:getByColor x xs
                             | otherwise = getByColor x items
```

This gives me a parse error on '{' when I try to run it.

Could anybody point me in the right direction??

Answer (score 3):

I was way over thinking my problem.
An anonymous function did the job.

Record syntax gives you automatic access functions, so i was able to do the following

```
getByColor :: Color -> [Shape] -> [Shape]
getByColor colorParam shapes = filter (\shape -> color shape == colorParam) shapes
```

Comment: you can write `(\shape -> color shape == colorParam)` as `((== colorParam) . color)`

Comment: @Simon: Or, with `Control.Arrow`, as `color >>> (== colorParam)`!

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but some advice. Using sum types and record syntax in combination is generally discouraged, as non-total use of record fields can hide errors from the compiler and defer until runtime. For example, if `width` is called on a `Shape`, the code will compile, but in the case the Shape is a `Square`, an exception will be raised during runtime.

It'd usually make sense to put the shape-specific behavior into their own types, and parameterize the constructors in Shape by new types - only using a record field if it is total - defined for all constructors.

I'd suggest against using record syntax at all in this case though, as you can simply define all the fields you want as independent functions on regular products - and don't expose the Shape constructors from the module - just some functions to create them.

```
module Shape (Shape, square, rectangle, length, color, width) where

import Prelude hiding (length)

data Shape = Square Float Color
           | Rectangle Float Float Color
           deriving (Eq, Show)

square = Square
rectangle = Rectangle

length (Square l _) = l
length (Rectangle l _ _) = l

color (Square _ c) = c
color (Rectangle _ _ c) = c

width (Rectangle _ w _) = Just w
width _ = Nothing
```